# Is user friend with me?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to see if **X** is a friend of mine using Facebook's Graph API. I was thinking about searching in the */me/friends* data but figured that'd be too heavy for my back end.

Appreciate all answers!

Comment: searching me/friends is a way to go. You can also do FQL query if you want. But wait - do you want us to do all the coding for you?..

Comment: I actually have no idea how to work with FQL so if you could supply me with a link or something to point me in the right direction I'll mark that as an answer. @avs099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is [FQL query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/) you need to run:

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() and uid2 = YOUR_FRIEND_ID
```

here is the URL where you can play with this query:

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me()%20and%20uid2%20%3D%20YOUR_FRIEND_ID

and this is URL you can call to get that data in JSON format:

> https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()+and+uid2=YOUR_FRIEND_ID&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

obviously you need to replace `YOUR_FRIEND_ID` with your friend's id, and you need to get `YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN` - the easiest way would be [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

so if query returns any data - that means you and `YOUR_FRIEND_ID` are friends.